# SassMeister online interpreter: Invalid CSS, expected "{", was ""

Tags: css, sass

When I copy and paste this sass into the online sass converter I get an error which is weird because the original project worked. Can you spot the error? I can't. It usually works right out of the box. This is the working project on codepen.io: https://codepen.io/LandonSchropp/pen/xLtif

```
html, body, h1

height: 100%
width: 100%

body
transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
background-color: hsl(350, 100%, 50%)

// in firefox, a transformed element causes a scroll when it extends beyond the element's size, so we'll disable it
overflow: hidden

font-size: 12px

@media (min-width: 480px)
font-size: 14px

@media (min-width: 640px)
font-size: 16px

.word
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive

svg
height: 100%
width: 100%
position: relative
top: -1rem
animation: pop-out 2s ease-in-out infinite

.word
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive
letter-spacing: 0.05em
color: white
padding: 0.5em

font-size: 28px

@media (min-width: 480px)
font-size: 36px

@media (min-width: 640px)
font-size: 48px

@media (min-width: 960px)
font-size: 64px

@media (min-width: 1280px)
font-size: 84px

p
position: fixed
bottom: 0
left: 0
right: 0
line-height: 2rem

text-align: center
color: transparentize(white, 0.25)
background-color: transparentize(#222, 0.0)

@keyframes pop-out
0%
transform: scale3d(0, 0, 1)
opacity: 1
25%
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
opacity: 1
100%
transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1)
opacity: 0

a, a:visited
color: inherit
```

https://www.sassmeister.com/

The exact compiler error is `Invalid CSS after "  color: inherit": expected "{", was ""`

Comment: What's the error? That's rather important.

Comment: The exact compiler error is `Invalid CSS after "  color: inherit": expected "{", was ""`

Comment: OK. Edit that into the question, and in the future, please include all errors from the start.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 issues here:

1. You need to change to the Sass syntax, because by default it's on SCSS which doesn't allow omitting brackets (which is what the error message is telling you)

   > [image]
2. Once you do that you'll get a more helpful error:

   > Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.

   This is because the Sass interpreter expects properties within blocks to be indented<sup>[[1]](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html)</sup>. If your interpreter was processing your code without any errors regardless of indentation it does not strictly enforce the Sass syntax specification. Try the code below, which is exactly the same, but with tabs added:

   ```
   html, body, h1

     height: 100%
     width: 100%

   body
     transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
     background-color: hsl(350, 100%, 50%)

     // in firefox, a transformed element causes a scroll when it extends beyond the element's size, so we'll disable it
     overflow: hidden

     font-size: 12px

   @media (min-width: 480px)
     font-size: 14px

   @media (min-width: 640px)
     font-size: 16px

   .word
     font-family: 'Bangers', cursive

   svg
     height: 100%
     width: 100%
     position: relative
     top: -1rem
     animation: pop-out 2s ease-in-out infinite

   .word
     font-family: 'Bangers', cursive
     letter-spacing: 0.05em
     color: white
     padding: 0.5em

     font-size: 28px

   @media (min-width: 480px)
     font-size: 36px

   @media (min-width: 640px)
     font-size: 48px

   @media (min-width: 960px)
     font-size: 64px

   @media (min-width: 1280px)
     font-size: 84px

   p
     position: fixed
     bottom: 0
     left: 0
     right: 0
     line-height: 2rem

     text-align: center
     color: transparentize(white, 0.25)
     background-color: transparentize(#222, 0.0)

   @keyframes pop-out
     0%
       transform: scale3d(0, 0, 1)
       opacity: 1
     25%
       transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1)
       opacity: 1
     100%
       transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1)
       opacity: 0

   a, a:visited
     color: inherit
   ```