# Getting Invalid css error when I dont have any missing "}"

Tags: css, webpack, visual-studio-code, sass, scss-mixins

I have updated my vscode to version 1.41.1.

After which I am possibly getting this error in one of my `scss` file. I don't have much knowledge of scss and work on react most of the time, hence having a hard time to find the issue.

I do not have any missing braces and I checked it well.
Here is the error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 1)

  --pf-c-accordion--BoxShadow: none !important;
                             ^
      Invalid CSS after "...BoxShadow: none": expected "}", was "!important;"
```

Approaches I have tried (but did not work):

[Error for invalid css when trying to compile sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417918/error-for-invalid-css-when-trying-to-compile-sass)

[SassMeister online interpreter: Invalid CSS, expected "{", was ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319092/sassmeister-online-interpreter-invalid-css-expected-was)

Css file:

```
// Bootstrap Core variables and mixins
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";

// Patternfly Core variables and mixins
@import "~patternfly/dist/sass/patternfly/variables";
@import "~patternfly/dist/sass/patternfly/bootstrap-mixin-overrides";
@import "~patternfly/dist/sass/patternfly/mixins";
@import '~patternfly/dist/sass/patternfly/icons';
@import "~patternfly-react/dist/sass/patternfly-react";

$co-affinity-row-margin: 15px;

.co-catalog-tile {
  height: 290px;
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -7.5px 0;
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-details__field {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-link {
  .co-clusterserviceversion-logo {
    flex-direction: column;
    @media  (min-width: $screen-xs-min) and (max-width: $screen-xs-max),(min-width: $screen-md-min)  {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  }
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-link {
  &:focus, &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;

    .co-clusterserviceversion-logo__name__clusterserviceversion {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  }
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-logo {
  display: flex;
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-logo__icon {
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
  width: 40px;
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-logo__name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-logo__name__clusterserviceversion {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: var(--pf-global--FontWeight--normal);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.co-m-pane__heading--logo
.co-clusterserviceversion-logo__name__provider {
  font-size: var(--pf-global--FontSize--sm);
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-empty__state__namespace {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: var(--pf-global--FontWeight--bold);
}

.co-crd-card-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 15px;

  .pf-c-card {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}

.co-operand-details__compact-expand {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.co-operand-details__section--info dd {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.co-catalog-install-modal .modal-header .co-clusterserviceversion-logo__icon {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.co-catalog-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.co-catalogsource-list__section {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.co-catalogsource-list__section__packages {
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.co-clusterserviceversion-row__status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.co-spec-descriptor--resource-requirements {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.co-spec-descriptor--switch {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
}

.co-create-operand__accordion {
  --pf-c-accordion--BoxShadow: none !important;
  --pf-c-accordion--PaddingBottom: 0rem !important;
  --pf-c-accordion--PaddingTop: 0rem !important;
}

.co-field-group {
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle--PaddingLeft: 0rem !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle--PaddingRight: 0.9375rem !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__expanded-content-body--PaddingLeft: 0.9375rem !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__expanded-content--Color: var(--pf-global--Color--100) !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--active--Color: var(--pf-global--Color--100) !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--active--FontWeight: 600 !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--expanded--Color: var(--pf-global--Color--100) !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--expanded--FontWeight   : 600 !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--focus--Color: var(--pf-global--Color--100) !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--focus--FontWeight: 600 !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--hover--Color: var(--pf-global--Color--100) !important;
  --pf-c-accordion__toggle-text--hover--FontWeight: 600 !important;

  .pf-c-accordion__toggle {
    border-left: none !important;
  }

  h3 {
    margin: 0rem;
    font-size: var(--pf-global--FontSize);
  }

  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.co-create-operand__form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.co-create-operand__header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  @media(min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    padding: 0 30px 15px;
  }
}

.co-create-operand__header-buttons {
  align-items: baseline;
  display: flex;
}

.co-create-operand__header-text {
  margin: 0;
}

.co-affinity-term {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px 0 5px 15px;
}

.co-affinity-term__remove {
  margin-left: auto !important;
}

.co-affinity-term__topology {
  display: flex;
}

.co-affinity-term__topology-input,
.co-affinity-term__weight-input {
  margin-bottom: $co-affinity-row-margin;
}


.co-affinity-term__topology-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.co-affinity-term__weight-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.co-operand-field-group {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px 5px;
}

.co-operand-field-group-title {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.catalog-source__table-row--disabled {
  background-color: var(--pf-global--BackgroundColor--200);
  color: var(--pf-global--Color--400);
}

.key-operator-value__action {
  padding: 0;
  width: 28px;
}
@media (max-width: $screen-sm-max) {
  .key-operator-value__action--stacked,
  .key-operator-value__value-field--stacked {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}

.key-operator-value__delete-button {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.key-operator-value__heading-button {
  height: 23px; // for vertical alignment with input field; equals $pf-global--LineHeight--md
}

.key-operator-value__name-field,
.key-operator-value__operator-field,
.key-operator-value__value-field {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.key-operator-value__row {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You may need to show more of your scss file in order for us to help.

Comment: updated the css file!